# How do I create a Table of Contents based on '.. http' directive on Sphinx (sphinxcontrib.httpdomain)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I would like to create a Table of Contents for my page based on `.. http` directive on [sphinxcontrib.httpdomain](https://sphinxcontrib-httpdomain.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), an extension of Sphinx.

My "sections" are "defined" by `.. http:get:: /user`, `.. http:post:: /user` and `.. http:delete:: /user` Sphinx directives. 
The created permalink for each "section" would be: `#get--ms3-user`, `#post--ms3-user` and `#delete--ms3-user`

Would it be possible? This TOC would be as a section list that when I click on one item, I will go to the "section".

I've tried to look for it on the internet, but I was not able to find something that may help me.

I give below an example of my page.

Thank you in advance.

**user.rst**

```
User
****


.. http:get:: /user

   **Example request**:

   .. sourcecode:: http

      GET /ms3/user HTTP/1.1      
      Host: example.com

   **Example response**:

   .. sourcecode:: http

      HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      Content-Type: application/json

      [
        {
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "username": "test",
        }
      ]

   ...


.. http:post:: /user


   **Example request**:

   ...

   **Example response**:

   ...


.. http:delete:: /ms3/user

   **Example request**:

   ...
```

**EDIT 1: An idea**

The following example is an attempt to create this TOC.
This approach works, but I built it manually.
I would like an automatic approach, if it is possible.

```
* `GET /ms3/user <#get--ms3-user>`_
* `POST /ms3/user <#post--ms3-user>`_
* `DELETE /ms3/user <#delete--ms3-user>`_
```

Comment: What is the `http` tag in Sphinx? There is no such [directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html).

Comment: This directive is from [sphinxcontrib-httpdomain](https://sphinxcontrib-httpdomain.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work with `sphinxcontrib-httpdomain`, but give these guesses a try:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    user
```

And if that does not work, insert a section heading above each `http` directive in `user.rst`:

```
get ms3 user
------------

.. http:get:: /user
```

And if that *still* doesn't work, then insert an arbitrary target above the heading.

```
.. _get--ms3-user:

get ms3 user
------------

.. http:get:: /user
```

Comment: Your first tip works well if I have sections on my page, for that reason, I've needed to use the second tip together.
The only problem is that the `.. http:get:: /user` directive has already created a "fake section" (1) automatically, then it inserts a new section above this directive, becoming redundant.
(1) What I would like to say with "fake section" is that the directive creates a section `get ms3 user` on my page, but it does not insert this "section" on TOC tree, because of that, this "section" does not appear on your first tip.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I cannot understand your comment. Maybe update your question with the source HTML code (actual code, not a screenshot of it) that gets generated?